# Indian Citizen Passport Lost issued in another Country

Tags: visas, passports, indian-citizens

My Friend who is an Indian Citizen holding an Indian Passport. When he went to work in one Of the British Overseas Territory, somehow he lost his Passport. Now his new Passport that was issued in B.O.T(British Virgin Island). I want to know, Can he enjoy visa free or Visa on Arrival or Visa exempt entry to countries that BVI citizens enjoy?

Comment: Why do you think so?

Comment: Entry requirements are determined by a traveler's citizenship, not by the location of the office that issued the passport.

Answer (score 2):

Regardless of where the passport was issued, as long as it is a regular Indian passport, it has the same restrictions as it would have if it was issued in India.

Answer (score 0):

In case of lost passports, a new passport will be issued by the Indian High Commission in that country. It is an Indian passport, but the place of issue will be British Virgin Island (in his case). I faced the same situation before, and got a new passport from Indian High Commission in New Zealand after writing an apology letter for my negligence.